# Laravel 5 Route Best Practice?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. I would like to know how to write Laravel 5 routes in best practice.

Here is my route so far.

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

/* start contoh acl simple

Route::get('owner', ['middleware' => 'role:owner', function () {
  return 'cie owner masuk :p';
}]);

Route::get('manager', ['middleware' => 'role:manager', function () {
  return 'halo pak manager';
}]);

Route::get('denied/{role}', function ($role) {
  if($role){
    return 'hayo ngapain akses halaman '.$role.', emang kamu siapa? kan cuma client :p cie dah paham middleware nieh';
  }
  return 'boleh lah akses sini';
});

end contoh acl simple */

// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
// use LaravelPusher;
// Route::auth();
Route::get('/jembatan', function (){
  // $message = 'mantap coyyy';
  // $pusherx = App::make('pusher');
  // LaravelPusher::trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', ['message' => $message]);
  $messages = [
    "id" => 5,
    "jenis" => 'afdsa',
    "no_kendaraan" => 'L 1334 H',
    "status" => 'Menunggu',
  ];
  LaravelPusher::trigger('antrian', 'newAntrian', $messages);
  return 'success';
});

Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
///*
Route::get('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
Route::post('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

Route::get('/password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\AuthController@showResetForm');
Route::post('/password/reset', 'Auth\AuthController@reset');

Route::post('/password/email', 'Auth\AuthController@sendResetLinkEmail');

Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

//*/

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

//route inti

Route::get('layarAntrian/{id}', 'GuestController@layarAntrian')->name('guest.layarAntrian');

//owner
Route::group(['prefix' => 'owner', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'role:owner']], function () {

  //input showrooms baru >> assign manager (detail n salary)
  Route::get('showrooms', 'OwnerController@indexShowroom')->name('owner.showrooms');

  Route::get('showrooms/create', 'OwnerController@createShowroom')->name('owner.showrooms.create');

  Route::post('showrooms/create', 'OwnerController@storeShowroom')->name('owner.showrooms.store');

  Route::get('showrooms/{id}/show', 'OwnerController@showShowroom')->name('owner.showrooms.show');
  Route::get('showrooms/{id}/delete', 'OwnerController@destroyShowroom')->name('owner.showrooms.destroy');

  Route::get('showrooms/{id}/edit', 'OwnerController@editShowroom')->name('owner.showrooms.edit');

  Route::patch('showrooms/{id}/update', 'OwnerController@updateShowroom');


  //input manager baru
    // /managers
  Route::get('managers', 'OwnerController@indexManager')->name('owner.managers.index');
  Route::get('managers/{id}/show', 'OwnerController@showManager')->name('owner.managers.show');
  Route::get('managers/create', 'OwnerController@createManager')->name('owner.managers.create');
  /*
  Route::get('managers/create', function (){
    return 'x bro';
  });
  */

  Route::post('managers/create', 'OwnerController@storeManager')->name('owner.managers.store');

  Route::get('managers/{id}/delete', 'OwnerController@destroyManager')->name('owner.managers.destroy');

  Route::get('managers/{id}/edit', 'OwnerController@editManager')->name('owner.managers.edit');
  Route::patch('managers/{id}/update', 'OwnerController@updateManager')->name('owner.managers.update');

});


//manager
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:manager']], function () {

  //laporan keuangan, stock, aset

  //input accountant, operator, cleaner
  Route::get('employees', 'ManagerController@indexEmployee')->name('manager.employees.index');
  Route::get('employees/{id}/show', 'ManagerController@showEmployee')->name('manager.employees.show');

  Route::get('employees/create', 'ManagerController@createEmployee')->name('manager.employees.create');
  Route::post('employees/store', 'ManagerController@storeEmployee')->name('manager.employees.store');

  Route::get('employees/{id}/edit', 'ManagerController@editEmployee')->name('manager.employees.edit');
  Route::patch('employees/{id}/update', 'ManagerController@updateEmployee')->name('manager.employees.update');

  Route::get('employees/{id}/delete', 'ManagerController@destroyEmployee')->name('manager.employees.destroy');

    //aturan tarif, gaji, insentif
      // /pricings /pricings/create /pricings/{id} /pricings/{id}/edit
  Route::get('pricings', 'ManagerController@indexPricing')->name('manager.pricings.index');
  Route::get('pricings/{id}/show', 'ManagerController@showPricing')->name('manager.pricings.show');

  Route::get('pricings/create', 'ManagerController@createPricing')->name('manager.pricings.create');
  Route::post('pricings/store', 'ManagerController@storePricing')->name('manager.pricings.store');

  Route::get('pricings/{id}/edit', 'ManagerController@editPricing')->name('manager.pricings.edit');
  Route::patch('pricings/{id}/update', 'ManagerController@updatePricing')->name('manager.pricings.update');

  Route::get('pricings/{id}/delete', 'ManagerController@destroyPricing')->name('manager.pricings.destroy');

  // /salaries /salaries/create /salaries/{id} /salaries/{id}/edit


  // /bonuses /bonuses/create /bonuses/{id} /bonuses/{id}/edit

  // pindahan dari operator
  Route::get('materials', 'ManagerController@materialsIndex')->name('manager.materials.index');
  Route::get('materials/{id}/show', 'ManagerController@materialsShow')->name('manager.materials.show');
  Route::get('materials/create', 'ManagerController@materialsCreate')->name('manager.materials.create');
  Route::post('materials/store', 'ManagerController@materialsStore')->name('manager.materials.store');
  Route::get('materials/{id}/edit', 'ManagerController@materialsEdit')->name('manager.materials.edit');

  Route::get('materials/{id}/stock', 'ManagerController@materialsStock')->name('manager.materials.stock');
  Route::post('materials/{id}/update_stock', 'ManagerController@materialsUpdateStock')->name('manager.materials.updatestock');

  Route::patch('materials/{id}/update', 'ManagerController@materialsUpdate')->name('manager.materials.update');
  Route::get('materials/{id}/destroy', 'ManagerController@materialsDestroy')->name('manager.materials.destroy');

  Route::get('assets', 'ManagerController@assetsIndex')->name('manager.assets.index');
  Route::get('assets/{id}/show', 'ManagerController@assetsShow')->name('manager.assets.show');
  Route::get('assets/create', 'ManagerController@assetsCreate')->name('manager.assets.create');
  Route::post('assets/store', 'ManagerController@assetsStore')->name('manager.assets.store');
  Route::get('assets/{id}/edit', 'ManagerController@assetsEdit')->name('manager.assets.edit');
  Route::patch('assets/{id}/update', 'ManagerController@assetsUpdate')->name('manager.assets.update');

  Route::get('assets/{id}/stock', 'ManagerController@assetsStock')->name('manager.assets.stock');
  Route::post('assets/{id}/update_stock', 'ManagerController@assetsUpdateStock')->name('manager.assets.updatestock');

  Route::get('assets/{id}/destroy', 'ManagerController@assetsDestroy')->name('manager.assets.destroy');

});

//operator
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:operator']], function () {

  //tambah pelanggan
  //probably unused
  /*
  Route::get('clients', 'OperatorController@indexClient')->name('operator.clients.index');
  Route::get('clients/{id}/edit', 'OperatorController@editClient')->name('operator.clients.edit');
  Route::patch('clients/{id}/update', 'OperatorController@updateClient')->name('operator.clients.update');
  Route::get('clients/{id}/delete', 'OperatorController@destroyClient')->name('operator.clients.destroy');
  */

  //real operator
  // Route::get('clients/create', 'OperatorController@createClient')->name('operator.clients.create');
  Route::get('terimaPelanggan', 'OperatorController@terimaPelanggan')->name('operator.terimaPelanggan');
  Route::post('clientStore', 'OperatorController@clientStore')->name('operator.clientStore');
  Route::get('antrian', 'OperatorController@antrian')->name('operator.antrian');
  Route::get('antrian/{id}/show', 'OperatorController@antrianShow')->name('operator.antrian.show');
  // Route::get('layarAntrian', 'OperatorController@layarAntrian')->name('operator.layarAntrian');
  Route::get('updateStatus', 'OperatorController@updateStatus')->name('operator.updateStatus');


});


//cashier
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','role:cashier']], function () {

  //pindahan dari operator
  Route::get('antrianKasir', 'CashierController@antrian')->name('cashier.antrian');
  Route::get('antrianKasir/{id}/show', 'CashierController@antrianShow')->name('cashier.antrian.show');
  //list transaction in out
  Route::get('transactions', 'CashierController@index')->name('cashier.index');
  Route::get('transactions/{id}/show', 'CashierController@show')->name('cashier.show');

  //view detail transaction
  // Route::get('transactions/{id}', 'OperatorController@show')->name('operator.show');

  //create transaction form
  Route::get('transactions/create/{id}', 'CashierController@create')->name('cashier.create');
  Route::get('search/product', 'CashierController@autocompleteItem')->name('cashier.autocomplete');
  Route::get('search/customer', 'CashierController@autocompleteCustomer')->name('cashier.autocompleteCustomer');
  Route::post('transactions/additem', 'CashierController@additem')->name('cashier.additem');
  Route::get('transactions/deleteitem/{id}', 'CashierController@deleteitem')->name('cashier.deleteitem');
  Route::post('transactions/clearitems', 'CashierController@clearitems')->name('cashier.clearitems');
  Route::get('transactions/store', 'CashierController@store')->name('cashier.store');


  Route::get('transaction/{id}/export', 'CashierController@export')->name('cashier.transaction.export');

});


//client
Route::group(['prefix' => 'client', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'role:client']], function () {

  //topup
  Route::get('/transactions', 'ClientController@index')->name('client.transaction.index');
  Route::get('/transactions/{id}/show', 'ClientController@show')->name('client.transaction.show');
  Route::get('/transactions/{id}/export', 'ClientController@export')->name('client.transaction.export');

});
```

There is some test route, comment each role and so on.
How should my routes looks like?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no known best practice but it depends on your application and your preference. For a bigger application, to manage hundreds of route declaration easily, you may use a different approach but use the simplest one that comes out. Regarding your question, following is my experience for managing a bigger application routes in `5.0/5.1` in `2013/2014`:

Until now (Before Laravel 5.3), I've managed my routes in separate files, for example, my main `app\Http\routes.php` file looks something like this:

```
<?php

# Front End
require_once('Routes/frontend.php');

# Auth (AuthController Routes)
require_once('Routes/auth.php');

# Admin Back End
require_once('Routes/admin.php');
```

Now, it's obvious that, I've created a `Routes` folder inside my `Http` folder and for each section of my application, I've a plain `PHP` file, for example, the `admin.php` file inside `app\Http\Routes` folder, which looks something like this:

```
<?php # Routes/admin.php;

$router->group([
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'namespace' => 'Admin',
    'middleware' => 'acl'
], function() use ($router) {

        $router->get('dashboard', [
            'as' => 'dashboard',
            'uses' => 'DashboardController@index',
            'permission' => OWN_ACCOUNT,
            'log_description' => 'Landed on Dashboard.',
            'bread' => ['dashboard' => 'Dashboard'], // [routename => label]
            'menuItem' => ['icon' => 'fa fa-dashboard', 'title' => 'Dashboard']
        ]);


        require_once('Admin_Routes/user.php');
        require_once('Admin_Routes/role.php');
        require_once('Admin_Routes/tag.php');
        require_once('Admin_Routes/help.php');

        // Many More...
});
```

As you can see, the `Routes/admin.php` file also includes some other files from another folder called `Admin_Routes`, which contains all the other route files with `http:\\domain.com\admin` as base `URI` and also those routes requires a permission check so the middleware `acl` is used inside the group instead of all the particular route declaration.

So, this way I can group my route `prefix` and `middleware` and also it's more organized. Because it was a huge application so I needed a way to cleanly separate my routes.

Now, within this group, every included (require_once) files will also have the same URI prefix and middleware hook in common and I don't need to attach these in the route declaration, for example, the `app\Http\Routes\Admin_routes\help.php` file contains something like this:

```
$router->group(['namespace' => 'Help', 'prefix' => 'help'], function() use ($router)
{
    $router->get('/', [
        'uses' => 'HelpController@listAll',
        'as' => 'help.lists',
        'permission' => 'manage_help',
        'bread' => ['dashboard' => 'Dashboard', 'help.lists' => 'Manage Help'],
        'menuItem' => ['icon' => 'fa fa-question-circle', 'title' => 'Manage Help']
    ]);

    # More ....
]);
```

As a result, I don't need to add the `acl` in this group again and notice the `URI` inside help's route declaration, which is `'/'` and to access this route from my app I need to navigate to `http://domain.com\admin\help` but I did it group wie so I don't need to type the full `URI` again and this route also gets through `acl` middleware check because I've attached it within the parent group. Also, my `help.php` file only contains routes related to my `HelpController`, which is easy to manage (readable).

---

*Note: Please ignore the unfamiliar things like `permission, log_description, bread, menuItem` keys inside route declaration, these are my own implementation to manage couple of things depending on my application requirements and doesn't comes out the box with Laravel and may not fit in all cases.*